# Debug jasmine tests written in typescript node in vs code

Tags: node.js, typescript, jasmine, visual-studio-code

I have my unit tests written in jasmine and those are in typescript

```
// about.service.spec.ts
// say 4 to 5 test cases

// spec/support/jasmine.json
{
  "spec_dir": "src/tests/",
  "spec_files": ["**/*.spec.ts"],
  "helpers": ["jasmine-helpers/**/*.ts"],
  ...
}

// launch.json - vscode file
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [{
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Jasmine tests",
      "preLaunchTask": "debuggertests",
   }]
}

// tasks.json - vscode 
{
 "version": "2.0.0",
 "tasks": [{
    "label": "debuggertests",
    "type": "npm",
    "script": "test:unit",
    "problemMatcher": []
  }]
}

// package.json
// have to use jasmine-ts which is flavor over ts-node
"test:unit": "jasmine-ts JASMINE_CONFIG_PATH=spec/support/jasmine.json"
```

I have used this configuration to debug .spec.ts files in vscode but it did not fire debugger instead it run all tests and debugging started.

I have put a breakpoint in one of the test case of about.service.spec.ts but no breakpoint fired. Could anyone help me on setting up vscode debugging for jasmine tests?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below configuration will debug current test file - please open the required test file in VS Code and start debugging with this configuration:

```
{
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Jasmine Current File",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/jasmine-ts/lib/index",
      "args": ["${file}"],
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
 }
```

Answer (score 10):

In new jasmine-ts version, you have to include the jasmine.json to the args as this:

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Jasmine Current File",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/jasmine-ts/lib/index",
  "args": ["--config=jasmine.json", "${file}"],
  "console": "integratedTerminal",
  "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
}
```

To avoid this issue:

No specs found
Finished in 0.003 seconds
Incomplete: No specs found
Randomized with seed 60766 (jasmine --random=true --seed=60766)